# Naming a listobject with a string variable

Tags: object, listobject

```
Sub ShowHideTable()
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim tblTrngl As Shape
    Dim tblName As String

Call Shape_Clicked(tblTrngl)
Let tblName = tblTrngl.Name
tblName = Replace(tblName, "Trngl", "")
Let table.Name = tblName
```

I've debugged it and the `tblName` is exactly what I want it to be, but when I try to set the name of the `listobject` I get an error.
The last line gives an error no matter how I set it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nevermind I replaced last line with this Set table = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tblName)

Comment: you should answer your own question and set it as the accepted answer so ;)

Comment: @TroyPickens good that you wrote the answer, now please accept it as the correct one and get this question cleared. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set table = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tblName)